# Cocoa NSNotification monitor process

Tags: cocoa, process, monitor, nsnotification

I want to use NSNotication to monitor a process e.g. iTunes. I want a notification when iTunes is "available", the process of iTunes is running. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a notification for when iTunes is available, you'll have to post it yourself. This means you'll have to poll the process list, which means maybe you don't need a notification at all but can instead write the process polling code.

One example of how you can do this is with the shell command `ps waux | grep iTunes | grep -v grep`.

Comment: Could you provide me a coding example?